# PHP: refactoring count() to avoid warning "Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

Tags: php

I have a code that implements a stemming algorithm. One of the routines contain many lines similar to this one:

```
if(count($ret_str = $this->delete_suff(REDACTED LIST OF ARGUMENTS))) return $ret_str;
```

The `delete_suff()` function simply **returns a string** (which might be the **empty** string), or it may return **null** (see code below).

Running the code on PHP 7.4 I get the warning *"Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"*, which I would like to get rid of.

On the basis of my understanding, this is what the original code does:

- the `delete_suff()` function is called and the returned value is assigned to `$ret_str`;
- the assignment expression itself returns the assigned value (a string),
- this value is `count`'ed in order to check (`if` clause) that there was actually a returned value.

What is the correct way of refactoring this code to avoid such incorrect use of `count()`?

On a first try I would remove the `count()` altogether:

```
if($ret_str = $this->delete_suff(REDACTED LIST OF ARGUMENTS)) return $ret_str;
```

But I guess that this way the `if` condition would return false when `$ret_str` is empty - which would not be the original intended behavior since `count('') = 1`.

A second option I came up with is:

```
if(!is_null($ret_str = $this->delete_suff(REDACTED LIST OF ARGUMENTS))) return $ret_str;
```

Which one is correct? Or, if none is correct, what would be?

EDIT:
for completeness sake, this is the function that is called:

```
private function delete_suff($arr_suff,$str,$str_len,$where,$ovunque=false) {
        if($where==='r2') $r = $this->return_R2($str);
        else if($where==='rv') $r = $this->return_RV($str);
        else if($where==='r1') $r = $this->return_R1($str);
        
        $r_len = mb_strlen($r);
        
        if($ovunque) {
            foreach($arr_suff as $suff) {
                if($str_len-mb_strlen($suff) < 0) continue;
                $pos = mb_strpos($str,$suff,$str_len-mb_strlen($suff));
                if($pos !== false) {
                    $pattern = '/'.$suff.'$/u';
                    $ret_str = preg_match($pattern,$r) ? mb_substr($str,0,$pos) : '';
                    if($ret_str !== '') return $ret_str;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            foreach($arr_suff as $suff) {
                if($r_len-mb_strlen($suff) < 0) continue;
                $pos = mb_strpos($r,$suff,$r_len-mb_strlen($suff));
                if($pos !== false) return mb_substr($str,0,$pos+$str_len-$r_len);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would `! empty()` be the obvious choice

Comment: What values do you want to __exclude__ with this if clause?

Comment: @u_mulder: the called function may return a string, including the empty string, so my educated guess is the code is intended to exclude anything that is not a string. (I'm sorry but I've not written this code in origin, I'm reverse engineering its intent.)

Comment: `if (!is_string())` then?

Comment: @Nigel: if the returned string were empty, thus the assignment would return empty too, the original code would compute count() of an empty string, which is 1, and the if clause would be true. So, unless I'm wrong here, I think that `! empty()` would not reproduce the original behaviour.

Comment: @u_mulder: at first thought, yes, that seems to me functionally equivalent. But just `is_string()` without negating. This is indeed the core of my question: what would be a functional equivalent without using count().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refactor your code you should understand **what kind of values** you want to filter with `if` clause.

As you say in comments - you need only **strings**, including **empty string**, so this can be stated as

```
if (is_string($ret_str = $this->delete_suff(REDACTED LIST OF ARGUMENTS))) return $ret_str;
```

**Update**: in provided function body I see two `return`s:

```
return preg_match($pattern,$r) ? mb_substr($str,0,$pos) : '';
return mb_substr($str,0,$pos+$str_len-$r_len);
```

According to manual, `mb_substr` returns `string`.

Also there's one *implicit* return `null`, when `if` conditions are **not met**.

So, `delete_suff` returns either `string` or `null`.

That's why you can use either `is_string()` (cause `null` is not `string`) or use **strict comparison** with `null`:

```
if (null !== (ret_str = $this->delete_suff(REDACTED LIST OF ARGUMENTS))) return $ret_str;
```

Which ine to use - up to you to decide. But I would use `is_string` as it **clearly** identifies what data you need and what data should be skipped.

Comment: I added the function body to my question. If I'm not failing with my (mediocre) reverse-engineering skills, it all depends on the possible types of its return values (i.e. the kind of values I want to filter). To my understanding it may only return either one of: **string**, **empty string**, **null value**.
For all these three values the effects of `count()` or `is_string()` are identical. Still trying to challenge this hypothesis but looks like the right path to have a piece of code that is functionally-equivalent to the original intended one.

Comment: @Timido added an update according to provided funciton.